# OSX Swift, Unable to write movie at path

Tags: macos, swift3, avfoundation

I am using `AVFoundation` to capture screen recording and write it to a path. My app is sandboxed.

```
func captureVideo() { // Capture Method Code


    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .desktopDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("System")

    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Error creating directory: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
session.sessionPreset   = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium


    if session.canAddInput(input) {
        session.addInput(input)
    }

    if session.canAddOutput(movieCaptureOutPut) {
        session.addOutput(movieCaptureOutPut)
    }
session.startRunning()
let outputUrl  = URL(fileURLWithPath: dataPath.absoluteString)
    movieCaptureOutPut.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: outputUrl, recordingDelegate: self)



    let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: TimeInterval(5), target: self, selector: #selector(self.finishRecord), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)

}
```

But I am getting error:

> FigMovieFormatFileWriter::PostProcessMovie: WriteMovie() errored!!! -67452

I have checked write permission, as I can create 'System' folder. 
Any idea how this error can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

The outputUrl should be a video URL, you can change it to something like this:

```
let outputUrl  = URL(fileURLWithPath: dataPath.absoluteString)
.appendingPathComponent("test")
.appendingPathExtension("mov")
```

You can check the method's [API page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcaptureaudiofileoutput/1387420-startrecording).